# What is used as signing key when creating JWT (HS256) from client certificate?

Tags: vba, oauth-2.0, jwt, certificate, sha256

Note: Encryption is very new to me.

I'm trying to create a JWT for use in OAuth2 Protocol with client credentials flow and certificate as per these specifications.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

When sending the request with JWT as client_assertion I receive the error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS700027: Invalid JWT token. Unsupported key for the signing algorithm.\r\nTrace ID: XXXXX\r\nCorrelation ID: XXXXX\r\nTimestamp: 2021-12-22 15:40:56Z","error_codes":[700027],"timestamp":"2021-12-22 15:40:56Z","trace_id":"XXXXX","correlation_id":"XXXXX","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=700027"}
```

**I'm extracting the private key from ther certificate and using it as the key when signing via HS256. Is this correct? What key should I be using to sign the JWT when I have a certificate?**

Note: I've tried using it with and without the '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----' and '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----' with no success.

Here is how I'm calling the hash signing function:

```
propsRawSignature = base64UrlEncode(propvRawHeader) & "." & base64UrlEncode(propvRawPayload)
vHashedData = base64SHA256Encode(propsRawSignature, propsCertKey)
resultingJWT = base64UrlEncode(propvRawHeader) + "." + base64UrlEncode(propvRawPayload) + "." + vHashedData
```

I'm using a hash function [@HK1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504958/hk1) was nice enough to share in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068932/7303640):

```
Private Function base64SHA256Encode(strValue, strSecret)
    'original https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068932/7303640
    'also seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36386633/7303640
    Dim asc As Object, enc As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey() As Byte
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")

    TextToHash = asc.Getbytes_4(strValue)
    SharedSecretKey = asc.Getbytes_4(strSecret)
    enc.key = SharedSecretKey
    'enc.key = strSecret
    
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    base64SHA256Encode = EncodeBase64(bytes)
    Set asc = Nothing
Set enc = Nothing
End Function
```

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: In this specific use case only [RS256 is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) as the signing algorithm. Examples in VBA: [one](https://github.com/ststeiger/Jwt_Net20/blob/master/vbJWT/JWT.vb)  [two](https://github.com/krijnsent/crypto_vba/blob/master/ModHash.bas)

Comment: Thank you @identigral . Link one appears to be in VB, link two looks promising but I'm confused on how I would use RS256 signing with this. The methods available are: `Methods: default SHA1, other options SHA512, SHA384 and SHA256`

Comment: the 1st example: `string token = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, privateKey, JWT.JwtHashAlgorithm.RS256)`. Load their [sample project](https://github.com/ststeiger/Jwt_Net20/tree/master/vbConsoleTestApplication) and play with it.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach should be to use asymmetric encryption that works like this:

**CREATE YOUR OWN KEY PAIR**

Most commonly RSA256 is used, and that is a good starting point, though EC256 is considered stronger. Note that currently you are using HS256, which means Azure would need to receive the private key to verify the assertion.

**CREATE AN ASSERTION FROM THE PRIVATE KEY**

Only you can create this because only you have the private key. There is some [C# code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions) that you could translate to VB.

**UPLOAD THE PUBLIC KEY TO AZURE AD**

This is saved to `Certificates and Secrets` area, after which Azure AD can verify signatures. [This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496681/how-to-create-client-assertion-jwt-token-when-connecting-to-azure-ad) has some useful screenshots, and also some notes on creating keypairs for development.

**IMPORTING KEYS FROM CERT FILES**

First you need to ensure that the cert you have been given is RSA and compatible with Azure AD - see identigral's comment. You can generate your own one for testing if needed.

I would aim to write a console app that produces the assertion as a first step. Then translate to VBA later.

The key will need to be imported into a .NET object, preferably using one of the operations described in [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/c-sharp/pem-loading-in-dotnet-core-and-dotnet), eg `ImportFromPem`. You can then use digital signing as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=net-6.0), which is similar to what you posted above.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Archer . I should have been more clear in my OP that I've been provided a certificate from the service provider to use for auth. Specifically, I'm looking to know what exactly is used to sign the data. I'm reading it's the private key but do I remove the -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----, do I need to remove line breaks, etc.